# group by where items in associated table exist in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

Suppose I have 2 tables in an `sqlite3` database:

## `table1`

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
```

## `table2`

```
+----+-----------+------+
| id | table1_id | col1 |
+----+-----------+------+
|  1 |         1 | A    |
|  2 |         1 | B    |
|  3 |         1 | C    |
|  4 |         2 | A    |
|  5 |         2 | C    |
|  6 |         2 | D    |
|  7 |         2 | E    |
|  8 |         3 | A    |
|  8 |         3 | D    |
|  8 |         3 | E    |
+----+-----------+------+
```

## Expected result

I would like to return all the items from `table1` which have associated `col1` values of both `D` **and** `E`, namely:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
```

How can I achieve this using `sqlite3`?

Comment: If the question is unclear, please let me know what I can do to improve it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `table1_id` is a foreign key to `id` of `table1` then `table1` is not needed at all.

You should filter `table2` with the rows of that contain `'D'` or `'E'` in `col1` and group by `table1_id`.
Then set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT table1_id AS id
FROM table2
WHERE col1 IN ('D', 'E')
GROUP BY table1_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- the number of values in the IN list
```

If there are duplicates in `col1` for each `table1_id` change to:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT col1) = 2
```

Or with a CTE:

```
WITH cte(col1) AS (VALUES ('D'), ('E'))
SELECT table1_id AS id
FROM table2
WHERE col1 IN cte
GROUP BY table1_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=60d13733b1f91f52bbb2b5e517359ea9).

Comment: I don't fully understand the query you have provided, but I've tried it on my real dataset and it seems to work. It will probably make more sense as I work with it. Thanks a lot for your help with my questions today.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select  table_id from table2 t where t.col1 in ('D','E') group by table_id;
```

You could also inner join with table 1 to verifiy that the record exists on both tables