# How to query for all groups containing one required element and at least one optional element in sqlite3

Tags: database, sqlite

## Problem & expected result

Suppose I have the following table `t`:

```
id          f_id        col1
----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           B
2           1           C
3           2           A
4           2           C
5           2           D
6           2           E
7           3           A
8           3           D
9           3           E
10          4           A
11          4           B
12          5           C
13          5           D
```

I would like to select all distinct `f_id` such that `col1` contains one of the following combinations of values:

- A and C
- A and D
- A and C and D

The expected result would therefore be:

```
f_id
----------
2
3
```

## Own attempt

Based on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68090817/group-by-where-items-in-associated-table-exist-in-sqlite3/68091139#68091139) I tried the following query

```
SELECT f_id
FROM t
WHERE (col1 IN ('A', 'C')) or (col1 in ('A', 'D'))
GROUP BY f_id
HAVING COUNT(distinct col1) >= 2;
```

This query however also matches with groups which contain C and D, but not A. I do not want this because A is important. The above query results in the following:

```
f_id
----------
2
3
5
```

How do I obtain the desired result?

## Original script

For convenience, here is the code to generate the original table:

```
drop table if exists t;
CREATE TABLE t (id INTEGER, f_id INTEGER, col1 VARCHAR(1));
INSERT INTO t (id, f_id, col1) VALUES
  (1, 1, 'B'),
  (2, 1, 'C'),
  (3, 2, 'A'),
  (4, 2, 'C'),
  (5, 2, 'D'),
  (6, 2, 'E'),
  (7, 3, 'A'),
  (8, 3, 'D'),
  (9, 3, 'E'),
  (10, 4, 'A'),
  (11, 4, 'B'),
  (12, 5, 'C'),
  (13, 5, 'D')
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter the rows of the table so that only rows containing `'A'` or `'C'` or `'D'` in `col1` are returned and `group by f_id`.
Finally set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause, so that you get only `f_id`s that contain at least 1 `'A'` and any of the other 2:

```
SELECT f_id
FROM t
WHERE col1 IN ('A', 'C', 'D')
GROUP BY f_id
HAVING SUM(col1 = 'A') > 0
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT col1) > 1
```

If there are no duplicates in `col1` for each `f_id` you may change `COUNT(DISTINCT col1) > 1` with `COUNT(*) > 1`.

Or, with `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.f_id
FROM t t1
WHERE t1.col1 = 'A'
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM t t2
    WHERE t2.f_id = t1.f_id AND t2.col1 IN ('C', 'D')
  )
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=91a1b3f7ece8d68ea5a27222d1444149).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the order of the combinations is not important:

```
select f_id, group_concat(col1, '') agg
from t
GROUP BY f_id
HAVING (agg LIKE '%A%' AND agg LIKE '%C%')
    OR (agg LIKE '%A%' AND agg LIKE '%D%');
```

There might be a better way to compare (with regex for example).

Comment: what does the `agg` keyword do? Also, is there a way to do it such that I don't have to list all the permutations?

Comment: The `agg` is just an alias. I removed the last condition because it was redundant.